# Making an image only carousel with swiper JS makes some images resize themselves, how to change that?

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

When using SwiperJS, if an image has differing heights, the whole row "staggers" a bit.

[image: Problem that I am having]

I've tried using the usual `100%` width on the `img` tags and on other classes with no result whatsoever.